# Function to get previous business day given a date in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, function, date

Given an input date, I want to write a bash function that will output the previous business day. 
By this I mean the preceding ***week***day (Monday through Friday);
I don't need it to take holidays into account. 
So, for example, given "Jan 2, 2018" the result should be "Jan 1, 2018"
(even though that is a holiday),
but given "Jan 1, 2018" the result should be "Dec 29, 2017"
(because Dec 30 and 31 were Saturday and Sunday). 
I don't require any particular format;
just something that is human-readable and acceptable to `date -d`.

I have tried the following but the input date does not seem to be correctly taken into account:

```
function get_previous_busday()
{
    DAY_OF_WEEK=`$1 +%w`
    if [ $DAY_OF_WEEK -eq 0 ] ; then
        LOOKBACK=-2
    elif [ $DAY_OF_WEEK -eq 1 ] ; then
        LOOKBACK=-3
    else
        LOOKBACK=-1
    fi
    PREVDATE=date -d "$1 $LOOKBACK day"
}
```

I want to apply it for today:

```
PREVDATE=$(get_previous_busday $(date)) 
echo $PREVDATE
```

and for yesterday:

```
PREVDATE=$(get_previous_busday (date -d "$(date) -1 day")) 
echo $PREVDATE
```

But it is not working:

```
main.sh: line 3: Fri: command not found 
main.sh: line 4: [: -eq: unary operator expected 
main.sh: line 6: [: -eq: unary operator expected 
main.sh: line 11: -d: command not found 
main.sh: command substitution: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `date'
main.sh: command substitution: line 20: `get_previous_busday (date -d "$(date) -1 day"))'
```

Comment: Check `$DAY_OF_WEEK` (it is something other than a single integer value) and **always double-quote within** `[ ... ]`. Also, look at `PREVDATE=$(date -d "$1 $LOOKBACK day")`  And always run scripts through [ShellCheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) prior to posting here (It will find most errors automagically)

Comment: How about holidays?  By business day do you mean weekdays (vs weekend)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function to do what you want is:

```
get_previous_busday() {
        if [ "$1" = "" ]
        then
                printf 'Usage: get_previous_busday (base_date)\n' >&2
                return 1
        fi
        base_date="$1"
        if ! day_of_week="$(date -d "$base_date" +%u)"
        then
                printf 'Apparently "%s" was not a valid date.\n' "$base_date" >&2
                return 2
        fi
        case "$day_of_week" in
          (0|7)         # Sunday should be 7, but apparently some people
                        # expect it to be 0.
                offset=-2       # Subtract 2 from Sunday to get Friday.
                ;;
          (1)   offset=-3       # Subtract 3 from Monday to get Friday.
                ;;
          (*)   offset=-1       # For all other days, just go back one day.
        esac
        if ! prev_date="$(date -d "$base_date $offset day")"
        then
                printf 'Error calculating $(date -d "%s").\n' "$base_date $offset day"
                return 3
        fi
        printf '%s\n' "$prev_date"
}
```

For example,

```
$ get_previous_busday
Usage: get_previous_date (base_date)
$ get_previous_busday foo
date: invalid date ‘foo’
Apparently "foo" was not a valid date.
$ get_previous_busday today
Fri, Nov 30, 2018  1:52:15 AM
$ get_previous_busday "$(date)"
Fri, Nov 30, 2018  1:52:51 AM
$ PREVDATE=$(get_previous_busday $(date))
$ echo "$PREVDATE"
Fri, Nov 30, 2018 12:00:00 AM
$ get_previous_busday "$PREVDATE"
Thu, Nov 29, 2018 12:00:00 AM
$ PREVPREVDATE=$(get_previous_busday "$PREVDATE")
$ printf '%s\n' "$PREVPREVDATE"
Thu, Nov 29, 2018 12:00:00 AM
$ get_previous_busday "$PREVPREVDATE"
Wed, Nov 28, 2018 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to get the offset needed to get back to a business day.

1. You can write a case statement:

   ```
   case $dow in
       0|7)    backday=2;;   # For Sunday (either named 0 or 7) go back 2 days
       1)      backday=3;;   # For monday go back three (3) days.
       *)      backday=1;;   # For the rest, just one day.
   esac
   ```
2. You can use math:

   ```
   backday=$(( ((dow%7)>1) ? 1 : (dow%7)+2 ))
   ```
3. Or a lookup array:

   ```
   a=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
   b=(2 3 1 1 1 1 1 2)
   backday=${b[dow]}
   ```

For any alternative, you may use this (without error detection) function,
and some tests:

```
#!/bin/bash
get_previous_busday() {  dow=$(date -d "$*" '+%w')
                         backday=$(( ((dow%7)>1) ? 1 : (dow%7)+2 ))
                         prev_date="$(date -d "$* -$backday day")"
                         printf '%s\n' "$prev_date"
                      }

get_previous_busday "$(date)"
get_previous_busday $(date -d "-1 day")
get_previous_busday $(date -d "-2 day")
get_previous_busday $(date -d "-3 day")
get_previous_busday $(date -d "-4 day")
```

Will print:

```
Fri Nov 30 10:03:45 UTC 2018
Fri Nov 30 10:03:45 UTC 2018
Fri Nov 30 10:03:45 UTC 2018
Thu Nov 29 10:03:45 UTC 2018
Wed Nov 28 10:03:45 UTC 2018
```